# How can I introduce people to the Stack Exchange Sites?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, events, meetups

I am from a country where people are not very familiar with Stack Exchange sites and about 90% of them don't know their existence even if they use the Internet.

Maybe this question could not be asked here, but there is no other place where I can really ask it. I am ready for downvotes, but I need ideas.

So, what I want is to organise some open sessions in my country where students, professors, professionals... can meet and talk about Stack Exchange sites and their interest in our community. I realized that we are not opened enough to share ideas with others, but with Stack Exchange we can.

I'd like to know, what's needed for such events to occur. If there are some regulations from Stack Exchange, if there must be some people from this community and also as we may need T-shirts with Stack Exchange logo, if there is possibility for Stack Exchange active community to support with that.

I really want to see my people here too. And I am sure their mind can change.

Comment: The best way to start is probably word-of-mouth - if someone asks a question, and it's relevant to a SE site, tell them about it - "Gee, I don't know - but maybe if we look on the «subject» StackExchange, we'll find the answer there...", and then show them the site.

Comment: The [tour] page on each site can help, but I'd prefer if there'd be one about the overall network on stackexchange.com.

Comment: A lot of people are simply not interested in this kind of sites, and even if they knew them. I gave an example [here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2159/20058).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need SE's permission to organize public events, including demos.  The site is public, using the site is open to anybody -- go ahead, so long as your usage stays within site rules.  People have done this already; Kate Gregory told an anecdote here on Meta (which I cannot now find) in which she created a second account to demonstrate the new-user experience, but used her real name and started getting comments like "this must be an impersonator; Kate wouldn't ask that".

SE used to sometimes provide swag like t-shirts for events, but (a) it was more for things like big conferences and (b) I don't think they're doing that any more.  You'd be best off focusing on the sites themselves, not on swag.